# Crosstab report overlap

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jaspersoft studio 6.2. In my report, only one summary band, two crosstabs are placed vertically. The issue is the two crosstabs will overlap if I don't leave enough space for the top crosstab. But the truth is the row group is from a query so is dynamic, I will never know what height is enough (or too much) for the top crosstab. I am from other reporting tools (ssrs, crystal), this never been an issue, just wondering what's the best practice to deal with it in Jasper?

EDIT: added screenshots

The report definition in jaspersoft studio. There are two crosstabs in summary band. There is not much space between two crosstabs.

[image]

The result: you can see two crosstabs overlap.

[image]

The only solution I have is to put huge space between the two like this: The only problem is next time there may be more data and crosstab 1 may grow and will overlap again.

[image]

Comment: It is better to post the image

Comment: Set position type = Float of second crosstab. You can find it in properties - > appearance tab.

Comment: @FahadAnjum thanks, that works! If you put that in answer, I will choose it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set position type = Float of second crosstab. 
You can find it in properties - > appearance tab.